# gnuplot colorbox label position

Tags: label, gnuplot, colorbox

I'm using the view map feature with a data set that is often whole numbers. I limit the number of colors based on the range of whole values when the range is small. I'm looking for an option that will place the value labels at the center of each colorbox color range. For example I'd like "500" to appear at the center of YELLOW rather than the top, and I'd like "498" to appear in the center of BLACK rather than the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is your data what is your code so far? Is your colorbox vertical or horizontal? Could you please show your code and the result to make clear what you have and what you would like to have?

Comment: And to understand how it works here, I suggest you take some time to read some of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking . After, you can edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# colorbox centered at screen x=0.9, 0.1 < screen y < 0.9
# known range [0:10] allows us to calculate tic positions
# 
set colorbox user origin screen 0.85, 0.1 size 0.1, 0.8
set cbrange [0:10]

# custom tic labels for the colorbox
unset cbtics
set style textbox opaque border lc "black" margins 0,0

do for [i = 1:9] {
    set label i at screen 0.9, (0.1 + 0.08*i)
    set label i sprintf("%03d",i) center boxed front
}

# some function for which the cbrange makes sense
set palette cubehelix 
set sample 101; set isosample 101; set xyplane 0
f(x,y) = 10*sinc(sqrt(x*x + y*y))

splot f(x,y) with pm3d
```

[image]

Comment: In the end I modified the program that collected the data to also generate the gnuplot script on the fly. As I then had direct access to the data, I limited the colorbox palette set based on the range of values (which are all integers). This gave me just BLACK and YELLOW in my last test, which was perfect. I then centered the labels by adjusting the color box limits to [MIN - 0.5:MAX + 0.5]. This too was perfect.